# How many instances of AuthorizeAttribute class are created in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, authorize-attribute

I am doing custom authorization using a class derived from `AuthorizeAttribute` and decorating my controllers with it. Per my understanding, only 1 instance of this attribute class is created to serve all requests. Is this correct? I am using locking inside, so want to be sure it causes no bottlenecks due to a single instance.

PS: I am using locking to retain values between `OnAuthorization()` and `AuthorizeCore()` calls as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12879182

Comment: For all intents and purposes, you can assume that a single `AuthorizeAttribute` instance can service multiple controller actions each of which run in a different thread. I'm not sure that once instance serves *all* of them, but you can think of it that way if it helps. So yes, `lock`ing may bottleneck. It's like this with other action filters as well, not just the `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Comment: In my case, `AuthorizeCore()` calls an external webservice to check user authorization and locking will not allow more than 1 call at a time. Then is there a better way to do this, like implementing it in my base controller class?

Comment: If you are locking around a blocking operation like a network (web service) call, then yes, that sounds like a performance impediment. Implementing in a base controller would at least get each network call isolated into its own thread (same as the action being invoked).